# Cleanest way to loop over master set, processing each sub-set, in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, records

This is a common scenario and I'm never quite happy with the solutions.  You have a set of data, just assume rows from a db ordered by category in this case.

You want to build a buffer with a sub-set of each category, and on each category change, do some processing, then clear the buffer.  Assume that process() is wrapped in a bunch of complex logic that you don't want to duplicate

Anyone have a better setup?

```
# category, city
data = [
          [10, 'citya'],
          [10, 'cityb'],
          [11, 'citya'],
          [11, 'cityb'],
          [11, 'citya'],
          [12, 'cityb'],
          [12, 'cityg']
       ]

# do some heavy lifting in here
def process(buf) p buf; end

cur_cat = nil
cur_cat_buf = []
data.each do |r|
  if r[0] != cur_cat
    cur_cat = r[0]
    process(cur_cat_buf) #<-- assume this is conditional, complex
    cur_cat_buf.clear
  end
  cur_cat_buf << r[1]
end
process(cur_cat_buf) #<-- assume the conditional is duplicated...ack.
```

This is the other technique, and is just terrible.  Messy, awful! Always looking ahead, checking if it is nil or different etc...ugh...

```
cur_cat = data[0][0] if data.length > 0
cur_cat_buf = []
data.each_with_index do |r, i|
  cur_cat_buf << r[1]

  # look ahead
  if data[i+1] == nil or data[i+1][0] != cur_cat
    cur_cat = data[i+1][0] if data[i+1] != nil
    process(cur_cat_buf)
    cur_cat_buf.clear
  end
end
```

This is another alternative.  Certainly better than the last one.

```
cur_cat = nil
cur_cat_buf = []
for i in 0..(data.length)
  if (r = data[i]) == nil or r[0] != cur_cat
    process(cur_cat_buf)
    break unless r

    cur_cat_buf.clear
    cur_cat = r[0]
  end

  cur_cat_buf << r[1]
end
```

I want a clean, elegant solution.  There's gotta be a better way!

Comment: This kind of code has a name, it's called "imperative nightmare". You should really, really, learn about functional programming (in Ruby: map, select, inject, group_by, zip...).

Comment: Also, this "process" function is kind of smelly. Why do you have logic outside their modules?

Comment: Just a hypothetical example.  Just assume there is something going on there.  Yeah, totally old-school imperative.

Comment: @Steve. Read about functional programming and you'll realize you've lived in the dark all these years :-)

Comment: Also, without some samples of what you want to get as a result it's hard to nail down a solution, leaving this question as a candidate for closing because it's subjective and/or overly-broad. Provide a bit better target and you'll get lots of recommended solutions I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.group_by(&:first).each_value do |pairs| 
  process(pairs.map(&:last)) 
end
```

Or the equivalent, yet slightly more verbose, yet slightly more explicit:

```
data.group_by { |category_id, city| category_id }.each_value do |pairs| 
  process(pairs.map { |category_id, cities| cities }) 
end
```

Comment: What's up with the & trick?  I understand that :first is a symbol to the first method.  Doesn't seem like it is documented.

Comment: It *is* documented, but not in `Array` and yes, it is a bit subtle. Look in your usual Ruby docs, but under class `Symbol`. You will find `#to_proc`, that, plus `&` (convert to/from block) is where the magic happens.

Comment: I had doubts about using &:first. A more verbose but clear version would be: data.group_by { |category_id, city| category_id }.values. Added both approaches.

Comment: Thanks.  Found it.  That is an obscure little feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.group_by(&:first).each_value {|buffer| process(buffer.map &:last) }
```

Comment: This doesn't quite get it.  One step away.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't pay enough attention.